# How to find the first vowel in a string

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I'm trying to create a pig Latin calculator however am stuck on a certain part. Let's say I have the string "apple". To convert that you'd simply add "way" to the end giving you "appleway". I currently have this part done.

What I'm stuck on is something like the string "sports". For this you take the consonants before the first vowel, put them on the end and add "ay" giving you "ortsspay".

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can get the consonants before the first vowel in order to properly convert the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` parameter expansion:

```
${var%%[AaEeIiOoUu]*}
```

- The pattern `[AaEeIiOoUu]*` greedily (`%%`) removes the matched portion from variable `var` from right, here starting from any uppercase or lowercase vowel (`[AaEeIiOoUu]`) followed by anything (`*`)

**Example:**

```
$ var=sports   
$ echo "${var%%[AaEeIiOoUu]*}"
sp

$ var=foobar
$ echo "${var%%[AaEeIiOoUu]*}"
f
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "sports" | sed 's/.*\([a-z]\)[aeiouAEIOU].*/\1/'
p
```

one too many wildcards;

```
$ echo "spozzzzzzzzzo" | sed 's/\([a-z]\)[aeiouAEIOU].*/\1/'
sp
```

@Fiximan, not sure about that one;

```
$ echo "spozzzzzzzzzo" | sed 's/\(b-df-hj-np-tv-z\{1,\}\)[aeiou].*/\1/'
spozzzzzzzzzo
```

@Sundeep, yep that works...

```
$ echo "spozzzzzzzzzo" | sed 's/\([^aeiou]*\).*/\1/i'
sp
```

Must say I prefer heemayl's, raw bash +1, nice!

Comment: This does neither give all the preceeding consonants, nor does it stop at the first vovel (but rather the last, due to `sed`'s greediness) - also the first parenthesis does not include the beginning. Better use gnu `sed` with `sed 's/\(b-df-hj-np-tv-z\{1,\}\)[aeiou].*/\1/'`

Comment: or even simpler `echo "Sports" | sed 's/\([^aeiou]*\).*/\1/i'`