# How do you make a pig Latin translator using awk?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to make a series of commands stored in a file which, when executed, converts text or a file with English to Pig Latin, I know that awk has if statements to handle the use of where '-yay' would go and when to simply append the first letter to 'ay', but I'm unsure how to use them.

Comment: Add an example snippet and your desired output from that.

Comment: I don't have a working snippet, unfortunately, however the desired output would be like so: "Hello, I am very happy today" translates to 'ello-Hay, I-yay am-yay ery-vay appy-hay oday-tay'

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/318675/117549

Comment: There is no "simple" way to do this, you have to take into account all the exceptions inherent to language syntax and punctuation ("th" being one phonem, words ending with punctuation like "!" or "..."). This represents a lot of effort, I'll try to get you started but don't expect it to be perfect you'll probably have to mingle with it to some extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a character based translation, it's probably easiest to use `sed` rather than `awk`. The following script for example would perform a pig-latin translation for non-hyphenated English words:

```
#!/bin/bash
C=bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXY
V=aoueiAOUEI
while read -r line ; do
    echo $(echo "$line" | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' |
        sed "s/\b\([$V]\)\(\w*\)/\1\2-yay/;tx
             s/\b\([$C]\)\(\w\+\)/\2-\1ay/;:x" )
done
```

It involves a) to process the input line by line, b) to transiently break each line into multiple lines on spaces, and c) to translate each word as one of two patters: a vowel followed by zero or more letters, which translates into having a "-yay" ending, or a consonant followed by one or more letters, which translates into those letters followed by a dash, the consonant and "ay". The translated words, with punctuation in place, are then joined into a single line through the nested `$(...)` command, and  echoed.